# Character printing program not behaving properly

Tags: console-application, brainfuck

I have been making a program that outputs each character before a given one to the screen, but... I've been doing it with Brainfuck! :)

I would like to be able to input a character, and see all the characters that come before it. The code I have so far only outputs a space and then waits for the next key press before exiting.

```
++++++++
[>+++++++++<-]>.>++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]>+.+++++++..+++.>
++++++++[>++++<-]>.>++++++++[>++++++++++++<-]>+.+++ ++++++++++.
----------.>++++++++[>++++<-]>.>++++++++++
[>++++++++<-]>+++++++.
++++++++++++++.>+++++++++[>++++++++++++<-]>.---------.>
++++++++++[>+++++++++++<-]>+.--.--------.>+++
[>++++++++++<-]>+++.>++++++++++
..>+[,[>+>+<<-][>>-<<+>>]>[[-.]<]],
```

I've tried for ages to figure out what's wrong with this code, but everything I've done has messed it up.

Comment: Seems to me that bf questions belong on cstheory.stackexchange.com or perhaps masochism.stackexchange.com.

Comment: By the way, only the very last line actually prints the characters. The rest print `Hello and Welcome` to the screen.

Comment: It seemed to work for me, but only once. I get "Hello and Welcome!

YXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! "

Comment: @Jere Really? on my computer I just get a space and then it waits for user input and exits.

Comment: @Jere Huh. Maybe my compiler isn't quite so good as I thought...

Comment: @Jere I've got it working now, but I've noticed something weird going on. When I input a character, it prints all of the ones before, but also prints out a female and male symbol before them.

Comment: @annonymously question solved?

Comment: @Zeb I'm sorry, but I gave up on this particular endeavor a long time ago, and have since lost the code, so I can't test your answer. I'll upvote it though.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, try [this BF interpreter](http://brainfuck.tk/)

```
------[>++++++++++<+]>--.+<------[>---<+]>.
```